# How can I solve when I click OK it deletes the data but when I click CANCEL it also delete. It should do nothing when cancel is clicked

Tags: javascript, php

Here is the html.

```
 <a href="source.php?admin_id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>&username=<?php echo $_SESSION['admin_username']; ?>" 
                      data-toggle="tooltip" 
                      data-placement="top" 
                      title="Delete"> 
                      <i id="del" class="mdi mdi-close"></i></a>
```

Here is the php.

```
    $sql = "delete from admin where id = '$id' ";
$conn->query($sql);
```

Here is the javascript. (I don't know if this is the problem or not)

```
 const deleteIcon = document.getElementById("del");
    deleteIcon.addEventListener("click",(e) => { 
       const confirmVar = confirm("Do you want to proceed? ");
       if(confirmVar){
            return true;
       }else{
            return false;
       }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the click handler to a child element, the "i" element, but that will not prevent the parent link "a" element from going to its href when clicked.

You could call the delete endpoint programmatically when confirmVar is true in the JavaScript.  If you do this, the link "a" element would need to be changed to something else, or removed, so that the delete endpoint isn't always called when the element is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

[e.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) will prevent the link from trying to go to another page. In this example there are many delete buttons. The code is commented to explain, but in your actual code `container` will be whatever the element is you want to remove when someone deletes it. Also, change `id='del'` to `class='del'` since all id's have to be unique.

```js
// get all the delete icons (class='del')
const deleteIcons = document.querySelectorAll(".del");
// for each one...
deleteIcons.forEach(el => {
  // add a click event listener
  el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    // stop it from acting like a normal link
    e.preventDefault();
    // prompt the question
    const confirmVar = confirm("Delete?");
    // if OK, find the closest parent with the class 'container' and remove it
    if (confirmVar) e.target.closest('.container').remove()
  })
})
```

```css
.container {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.container a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <a href="https://google.com" class="del" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete">
  Delete Me <i class="mdi mdi-close"></i>
</a>
</div>
<div class='container'>
  <a href="https://google.com" class="del" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete">
  Or Delete Me <i class="mdi mdi-close"></i>
</a>
</div>
<div class='container'>
  <a href="https://google.com" class="del" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete">
  Or Maybe Me <i class="mdi mdi-close"></i>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: It works but only the first item gets the confirmation the following items are not getting confirmation and gets deleted right away @Kinglish

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood what you were trying to do. I think my revised answer will help you though. Take a look